# Not all values objects can be viewed with XCode Watch and Debug console

Tags: objective-c, xcode

For example, for some reason in `initWithNibName:bundle:` I can't see the value of `self.view.bounds.size.width`, have to stop the program and use NSLog.
When I type `self.view.bounds.size.width` into the watch, I get "Enter expression" message on the right.
When I type `print self.view.bounds.size.width` into the debug console, I get the following errors:

```
error: unsupported expression with unknown type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Is there any way to see ALL the values I can see using NSLog?

EDIT: By @Abizern's suggestion tried `p self.view.bounds.size.width` and `po self.view.bounds.size.width` - same result.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
p self.view.bounds.size.width
```

or alternatively:

```
po self.view
```

`p` is a simple print which works for values

`po` is for `print object` which essentially give the same result as an `NSLog`

Comment: Or even `p self.view.bounds` which works in recent versions of Xcode.

Comment: Tried both "po self.view.frame.bounds" and "p self.view.frame.bounds" - didn't work, still get the "unsupported expression with unknown type" error.

Comment: Are you setting the breakpoint in the scope of these variables?

Comment: Yes. To make sure I even set them right before and right after I use or assign this value and still get the same result.

Comment: Worked, thanks! "print self.view" that I tried before just gave the pointer value, "po" output is much more valuable. Still, why can't I use "po self.view.frame.bounds"?

Comment: because self.view.frame doesn't have a `bounds` attribute. you want self.view.frame, or self.view.bounds.

Comment: Also, because bounds is a CGRect; a struct, not an object. If you want to use po with it try `po NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds)`

Answer (score 4):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18923064/201828

Basically, bounds is not actually a member of UIView, but rather the layer. So just do:

```
p self.view.layer.bounds
```

This was driving me crazy, too :-(