# Why can't LLDB print view.bounds?

Tags: objective-c, lldb

Things like this drive me crazy when debugging:

```
(lldb) p self.bounds
error: unsupported expression with unknown type
error: unsupported expression with unknown type
error: 2 errors parsing expression
(lldb) p (CGRect)self.bounds
error: unsupported expression with unknown type
error: unsupported expression with unknown type
error: C-style cast from '<unknown type>' to 'CGRect' is not allowed
error: 3 errors parsing expression
(lldb) p [self bounds]
error: 'bounds' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) p (CGRect)[self bounds]
(CGRect) $1 = origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=320, height=238)
(lldb) You suck!
error: 'You' is not a valid command.
(lldb) …
```

Why did the first 3 attempts fail? Is there any simpler way to print `self.bounds`? Thanks.

Comment: You could always NSStringFromCGRect it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Starting from Xcode 6.3, we have a better solution. In short, you need to import UIKit for LLDB to know about these types:
`expr @import UIKit`. Check out [this article](http://furbo.org/2015/05/11/an-import-ant-change-in-xcode/) to learn some tricks to make your life even easier.

Comment: Of course, this conveniently may or may not work. I literally had one run where that worked, and the very next build and run, it complained about it, and I had to do `expr -l objc++ -O -- @import UIKit` instead...which worked. LLDB is just a mess currently...

Answer (score 57):

You can access it by

```
p (CGRect)[view bounds]
```

or

```
p view.layer.bounds
```

---

`view.bounds` is actually `view.layer.bounds`

It seems that the type info of `[UIView bounds]` is not available to `lldb`

Comment: Ah, the `layer.bounds` answer solves the mystery for me. Thanks!

Comment: Nice call.  Radar anyone?

Answer (score 15):

You gonna love [Xcode 6.3+](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-SW10)

**TLDR**

```
(lldb) e @import UIKit
(lldb) po self.view.bounds
```

> LLDB's Objective-C expression parser can now import modules. Any
>   subsequent expression can rely on function and method prototypes
>   defined in the module:

```
(lldb) p @import Foundation
(lldb) p NSPointFromString(@"{10.0, 20.0}");
(NSPoint) $1 = (x = 10, y = 20)
```

> Before Xcode 6.3, methods and functions without debug information
>   required explicit typecasts to specify their return type. Importing
>   modules allows a developer to avoid the more labor-intensive process
>   of determining and specifying this information manually:

```
(lldb) p NSPointFromString(@"{10.0, 20.0}");
error: 'NSPointFromString' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) p (NSPoint)NSPointFromString(@"{10.0, 20.0}”);
(NSPoint) $0 = (x = 10, y = 20)
```

> Other benefits of importing modules include better error messages,
>   access to variadic functions when running on 64-bit devices, and
>   eliminating potentially incorrect inferred argument types.

**PS**: If you also confuse p vs po

```
p == print == expression -- == e --
po == expression -O -- == e -O --
```

`--` is the separator between `command+flag` vs `inputs`

`-O` flag is for invoking the object `description` method

Answer (score 8):

With Xcode 6.3, we can import UIKit and then print the frame or bound of view

```
expr @import UIKit
p self.view.bounds
```

Comment: you are perfect. Now I can debug my apps much faster! It has even made the function `tan(double)` workable!!!

Answer (score 6):

LLDB does not support dot notation for message sending when using `p` and that's why

```
p self.bounds
```

doesn't work, but

```
p [self bounds]
```

does.

(It actually supports it for objects when you use `po`, though)

Also, LLDB doesn't have type information of non-objects available at runtime, so you need to explicitly provide a type by casting the return value.

Comment: Then why these work: `(lldb) p self.tableView`  
`(UITableView *) $1 = 0x0f35be00`  
`(lldb) p self.tableView.contentSize`  
`(CGSize) $0 = (width=320, height=4966)`?

Comment: Interesting. I cannot access Xcode right now, but my guts tell me that it may be the fact that `bounds` is not a property, whereas `tableView` and `contentSize` are. I'll double check in a few minutes.

Comment: All 3 are properties.

Comment: `p [self bounds]` doesn't work too. lldb is much worse for debug than gdb and you need to add the implicit type cast in this case

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the context when you running this. But looks like lldb cannot find the type of `self`.

In order for lldb to evaluate `self.bounds`, it need to know the type of `self` is some Class has property `bounds`. It cannot assume `self` is ObjC type because you may call it under such context:

```
void test()
{
    struct 
    {
        int bounds;
    } self;
}
```

so you get the error `error: unsupported expression with unknown type`

However, if you call it using `[self bounds]`, lldb knows that `self` much be ObjC type because `[]` syntax only apply to ObjC type. But since the type of `self` is not clear, it still cannot evaluate the result of `[self bounds]` so you need to cast it to `CGRect`

Comment: @GabrielePetronella at least dot notation works with `po`, I can't remember about `p`

Answer (score 0):

Try with following expression,

```
p self.view.bounds.size.width
```

or use,

```
po self.view
```

p - Print is only uses to print normal/simple values
while,
po - Print Object works same as NSLog to print value of an object

Answer (score 0):

I tried @an0's answer `expr @import UIKit`， but it didn't work.

Then I added a pch file, and add these lines of code in the file:

```
#ifndef PrefixHeader_pch
#define PrefixHeader_pch

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif

#endif /* PrefixHeader_pch */
```

Next, link the pch file to my project:

[image]

Run the app again, then I can use the dot notation in lldb console:

```
(lldb) po self.view.bounds
```

For how to add a pch file , see the answer here [PCH File in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26126037/4975761)